# Dynamic autocreate field issue on Django Form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a dynamic field because I need a personal message per group inside a Service model.

So, I have to create some fields dynamically on my service form.

This is my ServiceForm:

```
class ServicesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    role = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(ServicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       try:
          for elem in Group.objects.all():
            i = elem.pk
            service = kwargs['instance']
            group = elem
            if RoleMessage.objects.filter(service=service, role=group).count() > 0:
                default = RoleMessage.objects.get(service=service, role=group).message
            else:
                default = ""
            self.fields[elem.name+'_message'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': str(i)+'_message'}), initial=default, required=False)
      except:
        pass

    class Meta:
       model = Services
       fields="__all__"
```

And this is my ServiceAdmin:

```
class ServicesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = ServicesForm

  list_display = (
    'serviceName',
  )

  def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    fieldsets = super(ServicesAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
    if obj != None:
        limit = len(fieldsets[0][1]['fields']) - 1
        index = 0
        for elem in Group.objects.all():
            i = elem.pk
            fieldsets[0][1]['fields'].insert(limit+index, elem.name+'_message')
            index += 1
    return  ((None, {'fields': fieldsets[0][1]['fields'],}),)
```

And this is the error that I'm having when I try to open or create a service:

```
 Unknown field(s) (ServicesManager_message, Administradores_message) specified for Services. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ServicesAdmin.
```

My model.py is:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    serviceName = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=50
    )

   class Meta:
      db_table = "service"

class RoleMessage(models.Model):
   service = models.ForeignKey(Services, blank=False)
   role = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=False)
   message = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve solved the problem. Some things change in Django 1.8 and that implementations is from 1.5.

Here I answer my changes in order to solve the problem.

On my ServiceAdmin changes too:

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': (
            'serviceName',
        ),
    }),
)

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['fields'] = flatten_fieldsets(self.declared_fieldsets)
    return super(ServicesAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    fieldsets = super(ServicesAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
    newfieldsets = list(fieldsets)
    fields = ['role']
    if obj != None:
        for elem in Group.objects.all():
            fields.append(elem.name+'_message')
        newfieldsets.append(['Custom Message', {'fields': fields}])
    return newfieldsets
```